# Dynamics 365 On-Premise, Active Directory Account, IOrganisationService

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

My client is using On-Premise D365.
I need to connect with it using the SDK. Unfortunately the service returned is always **null**.

This is the code I have tried out.

```cs
private IOrganizationService GetService()
{
    IOrganizationService service = null;
    string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CRMConnectionString"];
    //CrmConnection con = CrmConnection.Parse(value);
    CrmServiceClient conn = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(value);
    return (IOrganizationService)((conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null) ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy);
}
```

The Connection string is like the following

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRMConnectionString" connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=http://contoso:8080/Test;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can you see some obvious flaws or mistakes?
Or
Could you give me an example of a working code?
Or
Could you let me know how best to fix it?

Comment: A few questions...  

1. Does your connection string include a username and password? (I assume you sanitized it for this post?)  

2. Are you able to confirm `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CRMConnectionString"]` returns a value?  

3. What version of the .Net framework are you using?  
As a side note, `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` is now obsolete. Consider adding a reference to `System.Configuration` and using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"]` instead.

Comment: Also, have you checked `conn.LastCrmError` and `conn.LastCrmException` for more details. Generally getting a null value means that there has been an error and you need to check the before mentioned properties for more information.

Comment: Hi Ryan, 1) Yes, 2) Yes, 3) 4.6.2. I will get back to you on the LastCRMError part tomorrow when I am back in the saddle. Thanks for taking the time out to look into the code.

Comment: did you manage to find out what the cause of the problem was?